# UIDatePicker doesn't show current day. How do I update it?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

In IB I set 28 of November. When I run iphone it shows 28 of November. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

But now I want to show current day. How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the picker to the date using NSDate class.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; // current day
[picker setDate:date animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

Answer (score 0):

//set picker date and time in this way

```
NSDate *date = [lodatapicker date];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMMM dd yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormater stringFromDate:date];
[label setText:dateString]
```